# Помогите сделать AWK конвеер

Tags: linux, bash, unix, awk

Задача такая, определить протоколы запросов использовавшихся при обращении к серверу. Для этого есть файл с записями такого формата. Помогите пожалуйста написат awk конвеер для этого.

```
121.180.116 - - [31/Jul/2000:18:34:40 +0400] "GET /~sch/zol/ HTTP/1.1" 200 3929
195.133.73.31 - - [31/Jul/2000:18:34:41 +0400] "GET /~sch/zol/default.htm HTTP/1.1" 200 3929
195.121.180.116 - - [31/Jul/2000:18:34:45 +0400] "GET /~sch/zol/images/babyru.gif HTTP/1.1" 200 7179
195.133.73.31 - - [31/Jul/2000:18:34:47 +0400] "GET /~sch/zol/images/babyru.gif HTTP/1.1" 200 7179
192.218.140.157 - - [31/Jul/2000:18:34:54 +0400] "GET /~sch/zol/ru/zolushka.htm HTTP/1.0" 304 -
212.176.33.16 - - [31/Jul/2000:18:35:02 +0400] "GET /~t-alex/Linux/linux_home.htm HTTP/1.0" 200 14422
64.209.181.52 - - [31/Jul/2000:18:35:10 +0400] "GET /~t-alex/Linux/item/BlackCat_02.htm HTTP/1.0" 200 14748
193.233.63.21 - - [31/Jul/2000:18:35:11 +0400] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 304 -
193.233.63.21 - - [31/Jul/2000:18:35:16 +0400] "GET /images/bg.gif HTTP/1.0" 304 -
193.233.63.21 - - [31/Jul/2000:18:35:16 +0400] "GET /images/mgul.jpg HTTP/1.0" 304 -
193.233.63.21 - - [31/Jul/2000:18:35:17 +0400] "GET /images/welcome_r.gif HTTP/1.0" 304 -
193.233.63.21 - - [31/Jul/2000:18:35:17 +0400] "GET /images/welcome_e.gif HTTP/1.0" 304 -
```

193.233.63.21 - - [31/Jul/2000:18:35:17 +0400] "GET /images/russian.gif HTTP/1.0" 304 -

Comment: "определить протоколы запросов" - что это значит? В примере, кроме HTTP запросов никаких других нет.  Вы сформулируйте задачу поточнее!

Comment: @Sergey, это просто маленькая часть большого файла

Comment: а протоколы то где?

Comment: @eri `HTTP/1.1`

Answer (score 0):

В каждой строчке убираем ковычки, затем выводим нужный кусочек строки. У меня получилось вот так

```
cat file.txt | awk '{ gsub("\"",""); print $8 }'
```

```
HTTP/1.1
HTTP/1.1
HTTP/1.1
HTTP/1.1
HTTP/1.0
HTTP/1.0
HTTP/1.0
HTTP/1.0
HTTP/1.0
HTTP/1.0
HTTP/1.0
HTTP/1.0
```

оно?